# Invoke-RestMethod from PowerShellScript doesn't work but work from commandline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to invoke a rest method from powershell script to get git changes from azure repo. When i run the whole process one by one command it works but when i try to run the whole script by writing a powershell script it doesn't work as expected giving empty output. can anyone tell what could be the problem here

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/<Org_Name>/<Project_Name>/_apis/git/repositories/<RepoID>/commits/$(Build.SourceVersion)/changes?api-version=5.1"
$userName = "Username"
$password = "<PAT>"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $userName,$password)))
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method GET
Write-Host $result
$changesFolders = $result.changes | Where-Object {$_.item.gitObjectType -eq "tree"} | Select-Object -Property{$_.item.Path}
foreach($path in $changesFolders)
{
   Write-Host $path
}
Write-Host $changesFolder
```

Comment: Please [edit]  the question and elaborate the vague "_it doesn't work_" in a (sanitized) [mcve] (an error message? or unexpected output?).

Comment: doesn't work as gives empty output like this: 
@{changeCounts=; changes=System.Object[]} 


but when i ran all commands one by one on powershell it gave output: 
@{Edit=1; Add=1} {@{item=; changeType=edit}, @{item=; changeType=add}}

Isn't this kind of behavior unexpected?

Comment: You've described your issue and as described, it's environmental. Your organization/enterprise is potentially using security/risk filtering tools, i.e., web filtering, traffic analysis, packet inspection, guarded controls, etc. may of the orgs/ents I support, block/disrupt anything that is using encoding, because this is what hackers do to try an circumvnet protections in play.

Comment: how come when i run from powershell command line it is able to get the response fine? and also isn't PAT requirement for authorization is for security.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how but i tried Invoke-webRequest instead of Invoke-RestMethod and it worked
But I had to make some changes in the header as well otherwise it was hitting the endpoint but still giving 203 status

```
$headers = @{
    Authorization=("Basic" + [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$PAT")));
ContentType="application/json"
}
$result = Invoke-webRequest -Uri $url -Headers $header -Method GET
Write-Host $result.StatusCode
```

Gives result and status code 200 as expected
note: without adding a colon before password/PAT while converting to base64string will throw 203 status

Answer (score 0):

The following example is working. Additionally, you can paste our resulting URL into the browser and check the answer from your org.

```
$user = ""
$token = "PAT"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
$orgUrl = "ORG"
$teamProject = "PROJECT"
$repoName = "REPONAME"
$commitId = "COMMITID"

$restApiGetCommit = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/git/repositories/$repoName/commits/$commitId/changes?api-version=5.1"

function InvokeGetRequest ($GetUrl)
{    
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}    
}

Write-Host "Url" $restApiGetCommit

$commitInfo = InvokeGetRequest $restApiGetCommit

Write-Host "Commit: " $commitInfo.changes

foreach($path in $commitInfo.changes)
{
   Write-Host "Path" $path.item.path
}
```